# Внешний ключ в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Внешний ключ в MySQL, по идее, добавляет строчку с одной таблицы в другую, если во второй совпадает внешний ключ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

внешние ключи используются не для объединения таблиц, а главным образом для проверки целостности ссылочных данных (ограничения внешних ключей). Т.е. например при удалении родительского элемента можно удалить все дочерние и т.д.или же при апдейте родителя - обновится все в дочерних.

Comment: но при обновлении потомков, с родителем ничего не происходит

Answer (score 2):

Все ж таки вопросы надо формулировать так, чтобы они были понятны тебе самому. А восклицания типа:"Когда огонь горит, она в бухте",- истолковываются читателями - каждым по-своему. Я уловил лишь то, что вопрос звучит о внешних ключах. Отвечаю как могу.

Внешний ключ - есть ссылка на родителя: каждый из жильцов дома указывает на тот дом, где он живет; а дом не только ничего не знает о своих жильцах, он даже не подозревает об их существовании. Внешний ключ - это дубликат первичного ключа - уникального набора значений полей (поля) родительской таблицы. Поддерживает целостность данных и отношения между сущностями (таблицами)